# UISplitView table navigation bar not shown

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to use a `UISplitView` but he navigation bar for my menu view controller never shows up.

1. I have checked "Shows navigation bar" in the navigation controller
   and typed in the title in my storyboard.
2. I have set `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;`

But the title is not there. I can set the title for my detailed view controller though. Could anyone please explain why?

Screenshot for connections
[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the storyboard showing the connections?

Comment: How are you presenting the split view? Pushing view by IBAction? Instantiating it programmatically?

Comment: instantiating it programmatically. I have created an instance in appdelegate.m file.